# How to perform an action when the user hits the keyboard's done button for a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I know there are lots of similar questions about this already, but after looking at many of them they are involving UITextField and consequently UITextFieldDelegate's textFieldShouldReturn method. 
However I have a UITextView, not a UITextField, and I want to know when the user has hit the done button on the associated keyboard.

I have a table view where when the user taps on one of the rows the table enters an editing mode and the user can enter text into a UITextView which is within a cell. Here is some code:

The cell containing the text view

```
class ReportTextEntryCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var commentsTextView: UITextView!
}
```

The creation of the cell, which is called from within cellForRowAt

```
func getTextEntryCell() -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextEntryCellID") as? ReportTextEntryCell
    cell!.commentsTextView.delegate           = self
    cell!.commentsTextView.keyboardAppearance = .light
    cell!.commentsTextView.keyboardType       = UIKeyboardType.default
    cell!.commentsTextView.tintColor          = UIColor.black
    cell!.commentsTextView.returnKeyType      = .done
    return cell!
}
```

The keyboard appears, the user can type text.

The table view controller implements `UITextViewDelegate` and `textViewShouldBeginEditing` and `shouldChangeTextIn` are both invoked. 
But I was expecting `textViewShouldEndEditing` would be called when the user taps the Done button on the keyboard, but it is not.

How can I know when the user hits the done button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit the `UITextViewDelegate` and set the `delegate` for your `textView` and then you can use the following:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        // User pressed Done
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```